# Sturm-Liouville - differential equations (eigenvalues/eigenfunctions)

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville problem

$$Ly=-y'',\qquad y(-1)=y(1)=0.$$

Please help me to resolve this issue, because for more theory and everything I read, I can not find a single exercise and resolved to get a sense of how to solve problems of this kind.

Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen this kind of thing.  Could you remind us (or me, anyway) of what $L$ represents?

Comment: I believe it's just the operator that sends u to it's negative second derivative, i.e. $Lu = - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we are looking for functions $y \in C^2([-1,1])$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb R$, such that 
$$ \begin{cases} -y'' &=\lambda y\\ y(-1) &= 0 \\ y(1) &= 0 \end{cases} $$
So let's solve the ode $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ first, using the exponential ansatz, $y(t) = \exp(\mu t)$, we get $\mu^2 + \lambda = 0$, so $\mu = \pm \sqrt\lambda$ for $\lambda \ge 0$, and $\mu = \pm i\sqrt{-\lambda}$ for $\lambda < 0$.

- If $\lambda > 0$, we therefore have $$y(t) = a\exp(\sqrt\lambda t)+b\exp(-\sqrt\lambda t)$$as general solution to the ode, plugin in $y(1) = y(-1) = 0$, we get 
  $$ a\exp(\sqrt \lambda)+b\exp(-\sqrt\lambda) = a\exp(-\sqrt\lambda)+b\exp(\sqrt\lambda) = 0$$
  giving $a = b = 0$, so $y = 0$ and hence no $\lambda > 0$ is an eigenvalue.
- If $\lambda = 0$, we have 
  $$ y(t) = at + b $$
  as general solution to the ode, giving $a+b = a-b = 0$, hence $a=b=0$, so $y = 0$ and hence $0$ is not an eigenvalue.
- If $\lambda < 0$, we have 
  $$ y(t) = a \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda} t) + b \cos(\sqrt{-\lambda} t) $$
  as general solution. We get 
  $$ \begin{cases} a\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}) + b\cos(\sqrt{-\lambda}) &= 0\\
                     -a\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}) + b\cos(\sqrt{-\lambda}) &= 0
    \end{cases}
  $$ This system has a nontrivial solution if $2\sin\sqrt{-\lambda}\cos\sqrt{-\lambda}= 0$, that is if $\sin(2\sqrt{-\lambda}) = 0\iff 2\sqrt{-\lambda} = n\pi$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, giving $\lambda = -\frac{n^2\pi^2}4$. In this case, a solution is $a = \cos\frac{n\pi}2$, $b = \sin\frac{n\pi} 2$, giving the eigenfunction 
  $$ y(t) = \cos\frac{n\pi} 2\sin\frac{n\pi t}2 + \sin\frac{n\pi}2\cos\frac{n\pi t}2. $$

Comment: Thanks for all your help. But there is something that I didn't understand. How did you find the values of $$a$$ and $$b$$ for $$\lambda<0$$.

Comment: @OlindaFernandes Note that when the system has a non-trivial solution, one equation must be a multiple of another. So I solved equation II, using that a solution to $-ak + b\ell  = 0$ is given by $a = \ell$, $b = k$.

Comment: But with equation 2 , sin is an even function and the minus of a coeficient turns positive. So I believe it's the first equation you want to solve am I wrong